# Describing a recursive type in Coq

Tags: coq

I want to define type that abstracts a human individual with following rules:

- A human is either male or female
- A human has a spouse with the different sex to themselves, and their spouse's spouse should be themselves. In the math term, `forall h : Human, spouse (spouse h) = h`.

So expectedly a human would have the type of `Sex -> Human -> Human`.

```
Inductive Sex := male | female.
Definition Human (sex_ : Sex) (spouse_ : Human) : Human := ???.
```

In passing I need to define a group of functions below:

```
man : Human -> Prop
woman : Human -> Prop
spouse : Human -> Human
```

How should I describe them in Coq? Besides, in what way can I then define instances of human individuals or define them in pairs? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I object to heteronormative programs!

Comment: You can't define `Human` as you have specified as an inductive type, since the condition that `spouse (spouse h) = h` means that the type would not be well-founded. It is possible to do this with `CoInductive`, though those tend to be difficult to work with in Coq.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prove properties about spouses extrinsically, here `traditional`. I admit though, that it's not as nice as I would like it to be.

```
Inductive Sex := male | female.

Definition other (s:Sex) :=
  match s with
  | male => female
  | female => male
  end.

Inductive Human := stephen | stephanie | robert | roberta.

Definition sex (h:Human) : Sex :=
  match h with  
  | stephen => male
  | stephanie => female
  | robert => male 
  | roberta => female
 end.

Definition spouse' (h:Human) : {h' : Human | sex h' = other (sex h)}.
  refine (match h with  
  | stephen   => exist _ stephanie _ 
  | robert    => exist _ roberta _
  | stephanie => exist _ stephen _
  | robertra  => exist _ robert _
  end); reflexivity.
Defined.

Definition man h := sex h = male. 
Definition woman h := sex h = male. 

Definition spouse (h:Human) := let ' exist h' _ := spouse' h in h'.

Theorem traditional (h:Human) : spouse (spouse h) = h.
  compute.
  destruct h; reflexivity.
Qed.
```

Comment: Thank you, but I thought I missed something in the description. Actually the second property of a human should have a constraint. I've updated the question. How should this constraint to be defined?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't mind your population of humans to be finite, (1) implement a finite graph, (2) define humans as male or female and give them an id (for example, a `nat`), (3) connect those humans in a graph. If you're unhappy with some of the ways it's possible to connect people, define a predicate `acceptable : graph human -> Prop` and stick to the subset of populations you deem acceptable, `{g1 : graph human | acceptable g1}`. You'll also want to define `marry : forall h1 h2 : human, male h1 -> female h2 -> {g1 | acceptable g1} -> {g1 | acceptable g1}`.

If you just want to talk about populations, whatever they might be, like we can talk about groups or fields, whatever they might be, you can define a population as any monogamous and heterosexual set of humans with gender.

```
Inductive sex : Set := male : sex | female : sex.

Definition population : Type := {human : Type & {gender : human -> sex & {spouse : human -> human | forall h1, spouse (spouse h1) = h1 /\ gender (spouse h1) <> gender h1}}}.

Definition human : population -> Type := @projT1 _ _.
```

The booleans can constitute a population.

```
Definition gender (b1 : bool) : sex :=
  match b1 with
  | true => male
  | false => female
  end.

Theorem acceptable : forall b1, negb (negb b1) = b1 /\ gender (negb b1) <> gender b1.
Proof. destruct b1; repeat (firstorder || simpl || congruence). Qed.

Definition boolean_population : population.
Proof. unfold population. repeat refine (existT _ _ _). apply acceptable. Defined.
```

Suppose you've proved something about any human in a population.

```
Conjecture P : forall p1, human p1 -> Prop.
Conjecture fact : forall p1 h1, P p1 h1.
```

You've also proved it for booleans.

```
Theorem boolean_fact : forall b1, P boolean_population b1.
Proof. apply fact. Qed.
```